# How to navigate to another page closing modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**What I'm trying to do**

When navigating from modal component, I wanna close modal.

In my current code, I can navigate to Detail page, but modal is still opening.

**parent component**

```js
toggleModal = () => {
  this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
}

<Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} swipeToClose>
  <Completed nav={this} />
</Modal>
```

**modal component**

```js
navigateWithClosingModal = () => {
  this.props.nav.toggleModal;
  this.props.nav.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', {
    item:this.props.nav.state.item
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            block
            onPress={this.navigateWithClosingModal}
          >
            <Text>Detail</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.props.nav.toggleModal}
        >
          <Text>close</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I would appreciate it if could give me any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to invoke the `toggleModal` callback by adding the parens, i.e. `toggleModal()`

```
navigateWithClosingModal = () => {
  this.props.nav.toggleModal(); // <-- invoke function
  this.props.nav.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', {
    item: this.props.nav.state.item,
  })
}
```